# Pandas - Converting 12H to 24H (but getting rid of 1900-01-01)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to convert a column of my Pandas DataFrame that is in the format `09:18 PM` to `21:18:00`. It (sort of) worked with:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format="%I:%M %p")
```

But the output is, now:

```
df['Time']    
1900-01-01 21:18:00
```

I already have columns for Year, Month and Day, so I'd like to get back only H:M:S without 1900-01-01 included.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does it need to end up in datetime format, or can it just be a string?

Comment: time of day stored as datetime will always show a dummy date. You _should_ be able to ignore it for most operations, and you can specify a custom format when outputting the dataframe to a file or for display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dt.time`

```
df['Time']  = df['Time'].dt.time
```

Comment: It is so beautifully (and amazingly) simple that I feel ashamed!
Thank you so much for saving my day, @W-B.

Comment: @HenriqueJunior yw:-) happy coding